# what is the use of tzdb_list

Tags: c++, timezone, c++-chrono

I have seen the reference of `std::chrono::tzdb_list` that

> tzdb_list is a singleton list of std::chrono::tzdbs, each of which represents a copy of the IANA time zone database.

Why do we need a list like this.

When I try to use this list, it only have one item and I can not modify it. I already use `tzdb` for time zone.

The list seems to be useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *almost* correct.  `std::chrono::tzdb_list` is very nearly useless! :-)

But when you need it, you *really*, really need it.

A very few applications need to run for months, maybe even years at a time.  And these applications need the very latest time zone database from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  And these applications are often highly multithreaded.

Think airline reservations systems.

Such an applications might have multiple threads accessing the time zone database simultaneously and need to upgrade from one version of the time zone database to the next, without stopping and restarting the application.

This is where `std::chrono::tzdb_list` can save the day.  On some OS's, the function `std::chrono::reload_tzdb()` will push a new database onto the front of the atomic, singly linked list that is `std::chrono::tzdb_list` if a newer version exists.  This allows an application to migrate from the older version of the time zone database to a newer version, at its own pace, however it can manage that.  For example the application might have its own system of atomic flags and mutexes for managing such a transition.

[Here is a brief article](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#tzdb_manage) that describes exactly how an application might periodically check for the existence of a new database, and add one if found.  The article was written for the open-source precursor to C++20, but should easily translate to C++20.

[Here is the specification](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.db) for the functions that access the time zone databases.

Comment: Beautiful article about reloading tzdb. There's one (sometimes) overlooked property of timezones: spatial coverage. I must admit I have no idea how to encode/version that with the C++20 chrono specs, but a `geolocate_tz(lon, lat)` function synced with `tzdb_list` would be amazing. I realize there might be little authoritative data for tz spatial coverage and the best thing we have today is possibly https://github.com/evansiroky/timezone-boundary-builder/. Since you're so close to this, are you aware of any IANA efforts to change that which might eventually leak into chrono @Howard Hinnant?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such change forthcoming in the IANA database.  The current mechanism for changing the boundaries of a time zone, is to create a new time zone that represents just the intersected area that is changing rules.  For example if a small area such as a county moved from one time zone to another, the IANA _might_ create a new time zone just for that county.

Comment: Right, that's happened a few times over the past few years, e.g. Ciudad Juarez comes to mind. In https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla we have the problem where we create a routing graph with one version of the software but then clients might run a wholly different version of the same software and they need be both forward and backward compatible to whatever changes in the routing graph (which holds the tz info). We solved it recently ok-ish in https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla/pull/4446 with your date library (still C++17), was just hoping there might be some future pain relief:)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Very interesting.  I hope your team keeps an eye on the IANA tz development mailing list (https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/) and participates when appropriate.  Real world experience such as yours is invaluable to such a list.